# google Colaboratory opencv xfeatures2d_SURF

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
!pip install opencv-python && pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

> Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages Requirement already satisfied:
>   numpy>=1.11.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from
>   opencv-python) Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages Requirement already satisfied:
>   numpy>=1.11.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from
>   opencv-contrib-python)

```
import cv2
cv2.xfeatures2d_SURF
```

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d_SURF'

Why does not it work?

Answer (score 1):

`xfeatures2d_SURF` is not a proper function.

Try: `cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()` to test your installation.

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/df/dd2/tutorial_py_surf_intro.html) is an tutorial showing how to use SURF in python.